# Ubuntu Server: Udev automount - can't unmount this USB drive. Any Idea?

Tags: server, usb, mount, udev

I use Ubuntu Server 12.04.03 LTS (without GUI) and wrote an udev rule:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="Mass Storage Device", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/%k /mnt/usbdrive"
```

This is works well, but then I want to unmount the drive with this command:

```
sudo umount /mnt/usbdrive
```

But it isn't work, and there isn't any error message. What can I do?

Comment: No error message after a command usually indicates success. What exactly causes you to believe that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: *Append* these rules into your .rules file, you've created:

```
 ACTION=="remove" KERNEL=="sd?1" RUN+="/bin/umount /dev/%k /mnt/usbdrive
```

```
 ACTION=="remove" KERNEL=="sd?1" RUN+="/bin/rmdir /mnt/usbdrive
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I think I need to add mkdir to my "add" action too. Right?

Comment: yes, you've do that ...! :)
try it, and tell the result ..!